# How to get the name of lists for comparison purposes

Tags: python

This may sound a bit funny, but this is what am trying to do:
I have two lists: `myList1` and `myList2`. I am passing these lists to a function that will perform a specific task depending on which list it receives (i.e., based on the name of the list, not content).

```
def listProcessor(data):
    if data == 'myList1':
        perform task1
    else: #meaning data is myList2
        perform task 2
```

Is there a way in Python 3 to inquire of the name of a list (or a tuple, dictionary, etc.) and do a comparison like this?  Obviously, the way I am doing it here isn't working since it's comparing the content of the list 'data' to the single string 'myList1', which isn't working!  :-).

Comment: uhmm ... looks like i need to learn the mechanics of posting on this site, as the final text appears quite different from what i actually typed!

Comment: Objects don't have names themselves, they only have ids. Aside from that, you're choosing a really bad way of doing this.

Comment: ok!  i get it now (relatively new to python programming).  So, how would i do this better?

Comment: @lookiluke use two different functions! Or let `listProcessor` (which should be named `list_processor` or `listprocessor` per PEP8) inspect the list to see which action should be taken on it. Probably both!

Comment: You can add a flag parameter to the function's parameter list. Or if `myList1` is accessible within the function's scope, check the `data is myList1` predicate. This compares two objects by their identity.

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you!  got it now! :-)  this is the very essence of object-oriented nature of python, isn't it? the explanations are clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. You can create separate functions if what needs to be done for each list really is completely separate.
2. You can update your function to either:

   1. Take two lists as an argument:

      ```
      def list_processor(list1=None, list2=None):
         if list1:
            # do stuff for list1
         if list2:
            # do stuff for list2
      ```
   2. You can add an extra flag, identifying what kind of action to be performed, and set a default as well:

      ```
      def list_processor(some_list=None, type_of_list=1):
          if type_of_list == 1:
              # do stuff with some_list as if it was list1
          if type_of_list == 2:
              # do stuff with some_list as if it was list2
      ```

You do **not** want to do what you initially proposed, for various reasons. One key reason is that in Python, what you may call variables in other languages are not "boxes to put stuff in" (as most textbooks refer to them).

In Python variables are actually just *names that point to an object*. The key thing is that *multiple names can point to the same object*; which will easily confuse your function if you rely on the lists "name".

Here is an example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> b.append('hello')
>>> b is a
True
>>> b == a
True
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 'hello']
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 'hello']
```

In this example, both `a` and `b` are pointing to the *same list object*. What you do with `a` affects `b`.

Answer (score 1):

So let's start with this: ***you really shouldn't do this***. Data is just data in Python -- the identifier (e.g. the name you're using to talk about it) means nothing to the program logic itself. It's only meaningful to the programmer.

That said, there's ways to do what you're trying to do, ***and they're all the wrong thing to do***. But they're possible, so let's talk about them.

`globals()` will give you a dictionary with keys of identifiers and values of, um, values, for all objects currently in the global scope. This means that you can do:

```
def list_processor(data):
    g = globals()
    data_name = next((k for k,v in g.items() if v is data))
    if data_name == 'myList1':
       ...  # do whatever you want here
```

Note, however, that you're looking through EVERYTHING in the global scope. First off, that's dumb since it's slow, and secondly, it's dumb because it's buggy. What if `myList1` isn't being passed from the global scope?  What if it's a local variable inside a function that never hits the global scope? Now your tricky hack fails.

The correct way to do this is to perform some sort of introspection on the argument being passed in as "`data`". For instance if `myList1` always has 8 elements and `myList2` always has 10:

```
def f_if_myList1(lst):
    """Do whatever we do if we pass myList1"""
    ...

def f_if_myList2(lst):
    """Do whatever we do if we pass myList2"""
    ...

def list_processor(data):
    if len(data) == 8:  # myList1!
        f_if_myList1(data)
    elif len(data) == 10:
        f_if_myList2(data)
    else:
        # not sure. raise ValueError()?
```